# VBA Handeling of Excel Cell containing both Text and Formula-Value

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I just started working with VBA for Excel and I ran into a problem I can't find the solution to. I want to make a macro that makes a copy of a sheet and renames the copy to what is specified in cell B8. Now, Cell B8 contains a string and a value (based on a formula) illustrated below.

Content of Cell B8

[image]

How do I get VBA to use the name (string and number) as the name of the new sheet?

```
Sub NewFunction()

Dim counter As Integer

Sheets(1).Copy After:=Sheets(1)

ActiveSheet.name = Sheets(1).Range("B8").CStr

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: change `.CStr` to `.Value`

Comment: I have tried that. It does not work.

Comment: What error message do you receive when you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, you can't use the "/" in the sheet name.  It might error, but Excel will just ignore it.

Secondly, you are changing the name on the wrong sheet.  You added a new sheet and then referred to the old sheet.

Thirdly, no need to use .CStr as the value of the cell is what you want, and since that is the default property, no need to use .Value either.

Comment: 1) I dont' think second advice is correct: after `Copy()` method the new sheet becomes the _active_ one while both this latter and the _old_ sheet have the same information in cell "B8" so that `ActiveSheet.name = Sheets(1).Range("B8")` would work (provided a valid worksheet name is being used) 2) on the third advice I only want to stress that it's not that there's _"no need to use .CStr"_, while it MUST NOT be used since `Cstr` isn't a property or method of the `Range` object

Comment: True, B8 should be the same on both.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments, thought the problem is not complacently solved. The call to "B8" `(ActiveSheet.name = Sheets(1).Range("B8"))` takes the `="CO"&RANDBETWEEN(1;800)"` instead of the actual string/value of the cell (CO 745).

Answer (score 0):

you were almost there

```
Sheets(1).Copy After:=Sheets(1)
ActiveSheet.name = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Range("B8"), "\", "-"), "/", "-"), "?", "-"), "*", "-")
```

where

- after `Copy()` method of `Worksheet` object, the new worksheet becomes the *active* one
- the VBA [`Replace()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264409.aspx) method `chain` is to assure you're not using forbidden characters for your new worksheet name

there remains the issue of possible duplicate names, which can be handled via a specific Function you can find around here if you search for

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That is a smart way to do it!